# Tagging in email or mobile view

Tags: google-groups, google-groups-tags

My Google group has the option "require at least one tag" enabled, and in desktop view users cannot post without a tag. However, in mobile view:

1. The option to tag is not even displayed on the new topic page;
2. Nonetheless, untagged topics still get posted.

Similarly, untagged emails get posted. (I have searched unsuccessfully to find out if it is even possible to tag by email.)

Is there anything I can do about this problem? How can tags be added in mobile view? Can tags be added in email? If I go to the effort of converting all my tags into categories (even though that isn't the ideal choice for this community), will I simply encounter the same problem?

Is there any way of actually enforcing the tags requirement? (Outside of continuous active moderation?)

I'm not even sure what the point of only allowing tagged posts is, if all it takes is a mobile browser to get around it.

Answer (score 2):

Nope. No way to add tags/categories to emails. Which is odd, given that you should simply add tags to the subject field.